# Identify houseplant with waxy dark green oval leaves with pronounced ribs

Tags: identification, houseplants

I inherited this from a friend after she passed away. It has since lost all leaves. They just dropped one by one. I kept watering weekly anyway. I cut back the stems that just crumbled to dust inside. I think it’s dead but wondering if there is any hope and how to care for it properly. Thank you!

[image]